# C-x C-f Edit File As Root

Tags: init-file, files, configuration-files

Is there a way to open a local file for editing as a root? I need to make some changes to a config file located at `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, but the Emacs tells me that the buffer is read-only.

Comment: Note that you should not need root permissions to edit a file located under your home directory. Check what you're doing.

Comment: Not if the owner of that file is `root`. Then it does not matter in which directory the file is located.

Comment: That's my point: root should not own that file. You should fix that.

Comment: Also, when I follow the suggestions in that question, I get the following error: `File /sudo:root@machine-name.hq.domain.org:/var/root/.emacs.d/init.el no longer exists!` Somehow the domain name gets appended and inserted into the command automatically even though I run it as `File /sudo::/var/root/.emacs.d/init.el`

Comment: Does the file exist? Have you or your administrator configured Tramp? Can you reproduce the problem when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: `/sudo::` is tramp shorthand for `/sudo:root@<host>:`

Comment: Is your `$HOME` set to `/var/root`? That seems kind of odd. Usually it's `/root` if you are logged in as root, or `/home/MadPhysicist` for a normal user called `MadPhysicist` (for example).

Comment: I was able to figure this out after changing the ownership and permissions as @Gilles suggested. For some reason, Emacs created these files as owned by the `root`. On another note, if I ever wanted to connect to a remote machine and edit some files there, would I do it using the Tramp package?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Yes, you would use Tramp to edit a file on a remote host. e.g. `/ssh:<host>:~/.emacs` to edit your `~/.emacs` file on the `<host>` machine.  See `C-h i g (tramp)` for full details.  If you mean to edit files on a remote machine as the *root user* on that machine, then see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2177687